# Website not responding while running data scraping python script on virtual machine, while script is working fine on physical computer

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-cloud-platform, python-requests, virtual-machine

I am trying to **scrape** options data from this [link.](http://nseindia.com)I am following code

```
url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY'
header = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
    }
r= requests.get(url=url, headers=header, timeout=100).json()
```

This code is working fine on my physical computer without proxy. But when i am trying to run same script on google virtual machine(debian 9), Site is not rsponding. Please suggest how can i resolve this issue.I am not much experienced with linux and virtual machines.

Comment: you need to pass proxy as well with request

Comment: i tried, website is blocking proxy on both physical as well virtual machine.

Comment: set the proxy on command line console of virtual machine. Then try "wget https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY "